# How to split a large XML-file with Perl::XML::Split correcly into smaller chunks?

Tags: xml, perl, parsing

i have a file that is too large to work with - it is a xmlfile with almost 100 MB

now i want to split it with xml_split

the file is named germany-test.xml and has got almost 100 MB - i want to have it split into pieces with 5 mb

i have the following code in terminal:

```
germany-test.xml | xml_split -s 5M -b germany -n 3 -
```

and i get back the results:

```
syntax error at line 1, column 0, byte 0 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14.2/i586-linux-thread-multi/XML/Parser.pm line 187
martin@linux-wyee:~/gis/test/test2>
```

what goes wrong here? Any and all  pointers into the right direction will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error at line 1, column 0, byte 0 of the pipeline, which looks badly constructed.

Run either one of `xml_split … germany-test.xml` or `xml_split … < germany-test.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that's the entire error message you get? Unless you have `.` in your $PATH (which you should not), it is more likely to start with:

```
germany-test.xml: command not found
```

you could do `cat germany-test.xml | xml_split -s 5M -b germany -n 3 -` but that may qualify as [UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat), so 
`xml_split -s 5M -b germany -n 3 germany-test.xml` would probably the best way to go.

Comment: hello dear mirod many thanks for the quick answer. Well what if i am triyn to split a xml-document that **allready has been** splitted so far!? is this quite doable. **Note** this document - we call it germany-test.xml has some notifiers and markups  right at the beginning and the end of the document that assign this document as allready splitted. **Ouestion**: Is this a problem? Do i have - doe to this - another command?! Well - i guess not!?   Look forward to hear from you - greetings

Comment: did you try? If you run into problems, you would need to show an example of the data, I can't really answer without seeing it.